# findViewById crashing when using a custom view with <merge> and <include> tags

Tags: java, android, merge, android-layout

I am trying to make a custom view using XML then retrieve its properties and edit them. This custom view is added into the test2 view several times with different id's for each. I have tried to retrieve the id for one of these custom views (player_1) then get the TextView (player_name), and edits its properties and no other views like the player_2 id view.

But I am not sure that this is this even possible? It renders fine, but I get an error every time I try to do this in code. I'm really not sure how to approach this, I can't seem to get inflate to work either to test that instead. Any ideaS?

Thanks!

Game.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.test2);

View player1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.player_1);

TextView player1Name = (TextView) player1.findViewById(R.id.player_name);

player1Name.setText("John");
```

test2.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/player_view"
    android:id="@+id/player_1"
/>
<include
    layout="@layout/player_view"
    android:id="@+id/player_2"
/>
```

player_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:player="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.merge">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/top_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        >
        </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

This is a cut down version of player_view.xml, I can post more if needed.

Also I have not worked out if it even prints the error message for this in eclipse, it goes into debug mode and does not explain any further what the issue is.

Comment: If you can explain bit more,what exactly you want to do ? Your TextView player_name is in a Linear layout top_view, but what the point of getting the player_1 View ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player_view.xml has unknown type, so the **include** is confused what kind of View is it. Try to do the next:
Use or create new PlayerView class, mergeable with player_view.xml.

Edit test2.xml to:

```
<PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_1"
/>
<PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_2"
/>
```

then inflate it in your code as following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.test2);

PlayerView player1 = (PlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_1);
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflate.inflate(R.layout.player_view, player1);
```

Do the same for player2.